# Discrete Math Graph Theory Independent sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

An independent set is a set of vertices in a graph, no two
of which are adjacent. Let G be a graph with n vertices and with the
maximal degree equal to ∆. Show that, G contains an independent set of
size at least n/(∆ + 1).

Answer (score 1):

For any set $A$, let $\overline A = \{ x\ |\ x \in A \text{ or $x$ is adjacent to } A\}$. Note that $$\overline A = \bigcup_{x \in A} \overline{\{x\}}$$
Now since any vertex can have at most $\Delta$ neighbors, $\left|\overline{\{x\}}\right| \le \Delta + 1$ (where $|X|$ is the cardinality of $X$). Therefore
$$\left|\overline A\right| \le \sum_{x\in A} \left|\overline{\{x\}}\right| \le \sum_{x\in A} (\Delta + 1) = |A|(\Delta + 1)$$

If $|A| < \frac{n}{\Delta + 1}$, then $\left|\overline A\right| < n$, which means that there is at least one element $a \in G$ that is not in $\overline A$. If $A$ is independent, then so is $A\cup\{a\}$. Therefore any independent set can be extended until the set has at least $\frac{n}{\Delta + 1}$ independent vertices.